# Backbone Newbie: Approaching layouts

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a backbone app (linked to rails) that currently looks a lot like a standard RESTful resource.

I currently have a 'new_post' link on my index page called via the following:

```
  Backbonedemo.Views.PostsIndex extends Backbone.View

    # ...

    events: ->
      'click #new_post' : "newPost"

    newPost: ->
      Backbone.history.navigate("/posts/new", true)

    # ...
```

I'd like to include that on each of the backbone RESTful pages I have (index, show, edit, etc) and I'm wondering how to do it.

My initial plan was to place the #new_post html in the (non-backbone) parent rails template, but I couldn't figure out where to bind an event from each backbone view.

Alternatively, I guess I could throw in some sort of layouts in the (eco) templating system.

Last - and least desirable - is to set up a click #new_post event in each view, and render it in each backbone template. Blergh.

So, what's the most elegant way of approaching this? Is there a place to elegantly place event bindings across multiple templates? Ie the router or something, and if so, how?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If on click the only action is to change the route of the page, you can simply make the `#new_post` a link to `/post/new` and skip making any programmatic changes.